# What does the function ls() do for environment in R

Tags: r, debugging

I run the following code

```
sapply( 0:3, function(x){ls(envir = sys.frame(x))} )
```

And get the following result

```
[[1]]
[1] "mat"         "mat_inverse"

[[2]]
[1] "FUN"       "simplify"  "USE.NAMES" "X"        

[[3]]
[1] "FUN" "X"  

[[4]]
[1] "x"
```

It seems like it lists all the objects in the current enclosing environment; I do have mat and mat_inverse as two variables. But I am not sure what it returns for [[2]], [[3]], [[4]]. Is there a way to debug this code to track what this code does? Especially the following part:

```
envir = sys.frame(x)
```

is very confusing to me.

Comment: You can get the code for a function by simply typing the function without parentheses or arguments at the command prompt & hitting ENTER (ie, `>ls`). Note that you are *applying* `ls()` to the `sys.frame` environment for `0:4`, that is why you are getting a list of length 4 returned.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What does envir = sys.frame(x)) do?

Comment: I'm not sure; this is not something I've ever dealt with. From the documentation, `sys.frame()` allows you to access different environments w/ `0` being the top level of the stack. Maybe someone else knows more about this. More to the point, why are you running this code? What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: When you say *enclosing environment* actually you mean *call stack*. They are different, as in lexical scoping vs. dynamical scoping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.frame` allows you to go back through the calling stack. `sys.frame(0)` is the beginning of the stack (your initial workspace, so to speak). `sys.frame(1)` is nested one level deep, `sys.frame(2)` is nested two levels deep etc.

This code is a good demonstration of what happens when you call `sapply`. It goes through four environments (numbered 0-3) and prints the objects in each. `sapply` is in fact a wrapper around `lapply`. What environments do you get when you actually call this code?

Environment 0 is the beginning, i.e., your entire workspace.
Environment 1 is `sapply`. Type `sapply` to see its code. You'll see that the function header has `simplify`, one of the variables you see in [[2]].
Environment 2 is `lapply`. Once again, type `lapply` to see its code; the function header contains `FUN` and `X`.
Environment 3 is the function you defined for `sapply` to run. It only has one variable, `x`.

As an experiment, run

```
sapply(0:3, function(x) { howdy = 5; ls(envir = sys.frame(x)) } )
```

The last line will change to `[1] "howdy" "x"`, because you defined a new variable within that final environment (the function inside `lapply` inside `sapply`).

Comment: So the answer is ls() _does_ nothing to any environments other than spitting out the character representations of the named objects.

Comment: That is indeed the function of ls(), list all objects in current environment. The envir parameter dictates a different environment.